# Get the post id as early as possible

Tags: plugin-development

I have several posts that contains some specific dynamic content that expects certain parameters that are stored in post's custom fields. The site uses self-developed plugin that uses global $post->ID to get the current post ID.

At the plugin init hook the global $post variable is not yet populated, so it's too early to retrieve the parameters stored in the custom fields. So at that stage I can just retrieve some plugin config parameters, nothing post-related.

What hook can I add to my plugin code that would be triggered when the global $post variable is available? I'd then populate a global array variable that is later used by plugin's shortcodes.

Another thing to take into account here is that there can be run-time errors when processing the post-specific data. In case of error, I'd like to redirect to an error page. So this means that I need to know the post ID before any content has started streaming to user's browser, otherwise the plugin can not perform http redirect to the error page.

Comment: Does this post address your issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22804/get-post-in-init-filter-or-action/30660

Comment: Helpful reference: https://www.rarst.net/wordpress/wordpress-core-load/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The earliest action you can use is 'wp'. You can read more about it here: [Action WP](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp).

Comment: While wp is the earliest action, one could argue that it’s not appropriate for code that may result in redirection.

Comment: It depends on what the user needs the query/post. WordPress would benefit from few more actions to handle everything done between 'wp' and 'template_redirect'.

Answer (score 1):

The [`template_redirect` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) could be appropriate for this.

> This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load. It is a good hook to use if you need to do a redirect with full knowledge of the content that has been queried.

You can see where this occurs in the request process in the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request).